# tablelayout that don't show all

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout, tablerow

This is a menu with tablelayout that have tree tablerows, one with two textview, other two listview, and finally a button to start the game...
and my problem is that the last tablerow with the button to start don't show in the device. i dont have any idea to fix this, help!!

My tablelayout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff02fdff"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#ff02057d"
        android:text="@string/nivel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff02fdff"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ff02057d"
        android:text="@string/dibujo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff02fdff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inicio"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ff02057d"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bt_1"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="#ff02fdff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
```